# Ubuntu base running pipewire has much louder audio than on windows dualboot

Tags: ubuntu, windows, audio, dual-boot, pipewire

I have the opposite problem most people have with audio on Linux. Linux is at least twice as loud as windows without using any digital/soft amps. I'm not even sure how to start diagnosing this since windows isn't as accessible for fixing things on your own.

Comment: If your problem is with Windows then your question is off-topic here.